# Quaternion for camera rotation

Tags: rotation, quaternions

I have an up vector , position vector of the camera and position vector of the object the camera needs to be looking at. Is it possible to compute the quaternion based on this information? How can I do that ?

I tried this -

I thought the camera (at A) is by default looking in direction given by up vector(U). From there it needs to turn towards the object(B). Therefore final direction will be B-A. So I compute the angle and axis of rotation from U to B-A. But that doesn't give the right answer.

Comment: You got some feedback on CS.SE with suggestions on how to improve your question.  Rather than just copy-pasting your question on another site without changing it, it would be better to edit the question to address the feedback you've already received (e.g., to add additional context  about the specific conventions you're using and what you mean by "doesn't give the right answer").

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to stackexchange and stackoverflow and did not know the rules. I have deleted the other post.
By 'does not give the write answer', I mean that the XML file generated for the given configuration shows a value of <\quaternion> different from what I am getting.